# Connection to HP ALM with macro using proxy

Tags: excel, alm, hp-quality-center, vba

I am using TDApiOle80.TDConnection within my vba code to connect to HP ALM. But when i try to connect to HP ALM remotely i need to use proxy. Is there a way/method by which we can use proxy inside vba to connect with ALM.

Answer (score 0):

User ConnectionSettings Object to set the proxy and port.

```
Single sign on connection (C#)// configure connection settings
ConnectionSettings cs = new ConnectionSettings(); 

cs.ExecutionMode =  
    TDAPI_EXECUTION_MODES.EXECUTION_MODE_INTERACTIVE; 
     cs.BasicAuthHeaderMode =     TDAPI_BASIC_AUTH_HEADER_MODES.HEADER_MODE_ONCE;
     cs.SetWebServerCredentials("login", "pass");  

// import to OTA Connection       
TDConnection otaConnection = new TDConnection();      

otaConnection.ImportConnectionSettings(cs);

// pre-configure the connection to add Basic Auth Header at first request 

otaConnection.SetBasicAuthHeaderMode(TDAPI_BASIC_AUTH_HEADER_MODES.HEADER_MODE_ONCE);


// set user credentials        

otaConnection.SetServerCredentials("Login", "Password"); 

// init connect to ALM server       

otaConnection.InitConnection("http://<server URL>/qcbin");
```

Reference:
https://almhelp.saas.hp.com/en/12.53/api_refs/ota/